# Add input data to deep object React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create object based on user input. I did following till now.

It gives me following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined

```js
const App = () => {

  let passengerObj = {
        "primary": {
            "fullname": "",
            "age": null,
        },
        "secondary": [],
    }
    
    const [passengerdata, setPassengerData] = useState(passengerObj)

        return (
            <form className="passenger-form">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Full Name" 
                        value={passengerdata.primary.fullname}
                        onChange={setPassengerData}
                        required/>
                    <input 
                        type="number" 
                        placeholder="Age" 
                        value={passengerdata.primary.age || ""}
                        onChange={setPassengerData}
                        required/>
                  <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Full Name of Passenger2"
                            required/>
                        <input type="number"
                            placeholder="Age Passenger2"
                            required/>
                   </div>
                   <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Full Name of Passenger3"
                            required/>
                        <input type="number"
                            placeholder="Age Passenger3"
                            required/>
                   </div>
             </form>
  )}
```

**As I am trying to add primary and secondary data in passengerObj. So, I can save it. But, It want allow me to do that.**

Not sure how can I add primary and secondary data to Object using hooks.

Here sandbox I reproduce it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sunset-89ecj?file=/src/App.js:0-1184

Any would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you *expect* on calling setPassengerData directly from onChange? I'd suggest basic debugging - console.log(passengerData).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I highlighted my expectation in bold.

Comment: But you *aren't* trying to do that. You're replacing the whole state with the default argument to onChange. Again, do some basic debugging, you'll quickly see why passengerData.primary becomes undefined. This isn't really related to React or hooks, the same thing would happen in vanilla JS with a regular assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a common `onChangeHandler` which is dynamic enough to update multiple input elements.

Provide a name to your inputs. Supply a type(primary/secondary) & event to the handler.

[Updated working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-special-onchange-biw2m)

**Handler**

```js
const handleChange = (e, type) => {
    const { target } = e;
    setPassengerData(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [type]: {
        ...prev[type],
        [target.name]: target.value
      }
    }));
  };
```

**JSX**

```js
<input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Full Name"
        value={passengerdata.primary.fullname}
        onChange={e => handleChange(e, "primary")}
        name="fullname"
        required
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

What is actually happening in your code when you are entering some data for `fullname` or `age` the entire state object is being overwritten by the event object. So the object will not have any property called `primary` so eventually when you are trying to access `fullname` its giving error.

Please update your code with the below code. I have added two methods in order to update the `fullname` and `age` in the state.

```js
let passengerObj = {
  "primary": {
      "fullname": "",
      "age": null,
  },
  "secondary": [],
}

const [passengerdata, setPassengerData] = useState(passengerObj)

const setAge = (age) => {
  setPassengerData({
    ...passengerdata,
    primary: {
      ...passengerdata.primary,
      "age": age
    }
  })
}

const setFullname = (name) => {
  setPassengerData({
    ...passengerdata,
    primary: {
      ...passengerdata.primary,
      "fullname": name
    }
  })
}
  return (
      <form className="passenger-form">
              <input 
                  type="text" 
                  placeholder="Full Name" 
                  value={passengerdata.primary.fullname}
                  onChange={(e) => setFullname(e.target.value)}
                  required/>
              <input 
                  type="number" 
                  placeholder="Age" 
                  value={passengerdata.primary.age || ""}
                  onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
                  required/>
            <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
                  <input 
                      type="text" 
                      placeholder="Full Name of Passenger2"
                      required/>
                  <input type="number"
                      placeholder="Age Passenger2"
                      required/>
             </div>
             <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
                  <input 
                      type="text" 
                      placeholder="Full Name of Passenger3"
                      required/>
                  <input type="number"
                      placeholder="Age Passenger3"
                      required/>
             </div>
       </form>
)}
```

Here is another version which is generic method in order to update any input field.

```js
let passengerObj = {
  "primary": {
      "fullname": "",
      "age": null,
  },
  "secondary": [],
}

const [passengerdata, setPassengerData] = useState(passengerObj);

const setFormData = (name, value) => {
  setPassengerData(passengerData => {
    ...passengerData,
    primary: {
      ...passengerData.primary,
      [name]: value,
    }
  })
}

return (
      <form className="passenger-form">
              <input 
                  name="fullname"
                  type="text" 
                  placeholder="Full Name" 
                  value={passengerdata.primary.fullname}
                  onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
                  required/>
              <input 
                  name="age"
                  type="number" 
                  placeholder="Age" 
                  value={passengerdata.primary.age || ""}
                  onChange={(e) => setFormData(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
                  required/>
            <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
                  <input 
                      type="text" 
                      placeholder="Full Name of Passenger2"
                      required/>
                  <input type="number"
                      placeholder="Age Passenger2"
                      required/>
             </div>
             <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
                  <input 
                      type="text" 
                      placeholder="Full Name of Passenger3"
                      required/>
                  <input type="number"
                      placeholder="Age Passenger3"
                      required/>
             </div>
       </form>
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is closure on the `e.target.value`, check your answer, try typing something

Comment: This works perfectly fine, I don't see any issue. I have tried the same code in the sandbox provided in the question and is working as expected.

Comment: You are right, my bad, I thought it was `setPassengerData(prev => ...)` functional update, but still, this answer will recreate all functions on every render, I upvote as this is a valid answer

Comment: I agree on the point that all the functions will get recreated on every render, but then unless it's causing so much of performance issues using `useCallback` is also having its own drawbacks so haven't used that version.

Comment: Just few drawbacks, it will recreate all functions in every render (not so important), you won't be able to reuse such functions (like `setAge`) because of closures on `passengerdata`, meaning you can't pass it as a callback somewhere. But sure, for changing an input its a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `onChange` implementation, it accepts an `event` object and you trying to set the event as `passengerData`.

But there is another problem when using `setState`, [you want to use functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to not get a stale state.

But, using `e.target.event` in a callback will [have value closure on this value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#:~:text=A%20closure%20is%20the%20combination%20of%20a%20function%20and%20the,time%20the%20closure%20was%20created.&text=It%20creates%20functions%20that%20can%20add%20a%20specific%20value%20to%20their%20argument.), so you should use a reference with `useRef` hook:

This solution won't recreate `onChange` on every render (because of `useCallback` and functional update of `useState`), and also won't have any stale state.

```
const passengerObj = {
  primary: {
    fullname: '',
    age: null
  },
  secondary: []
};

const App = () => {
  const [passengerdata, setPassengerData] = useState(passengerObj);

  const inputRef = useRef();

  const onChange = useCallback(() => {
    setPassengerData(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      primary: {
        ...prev.primary,
        fullname: inputRef.current.value
      }
    }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      value={passengerdata.primary.fullname}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```

[image: Edit beautiful-sammet-mir70]

Answer (score 0):

This maybe hepls

[image]

```
function App() {
  let passengerObj = {
    "primary": {
      "fullname": "",
      "age": null,
    },
    "secondary": [],
  };

  const [passengerdata, setPassengerData] = React.useState(passengerObj);

  return (
    <form className="passenger-form">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Full Name"
        value={passengerdata.primary.fullname}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const {value} = e.target;
          setPassengerData((passengerdata) => ({
            ...passengerdata,
            primary: {
              ...passengerdata.primary,
              fullname: value
            }
          }));
        }}
        required/>
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Age"
        value={passengerdata.primary.age || ""}
        onChange={() => {

        }}
        required/>
      <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Full Name of Passenger2"
          required/>
        <input type="number"
               placeholder="Age Passenger2"
               required/>
      </div>
      <div className="secondary-passenger-data">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Full Name of Passenger3"
          required/>
        <input type="number"
               placeholder="Age Passenger3"
               required/>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**note**
`const {value} = e.target;`